# front coming in reverse order on flip effect on image

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net

I'm working dynamic slider that has dynamic name to. On mouse hover image will flip. Everything is working but the name are coming in reverse order below is my code. It's working for fliping on mousehover and dynamic name too but they are coming in reverse order

```
 protected void fillSlider()
        {
            cls_SliderMain objSlider = new cls_SliderMain(true);
            objSlider.SelectAll("");
            string strHtm = string.Empty;
            string[] imagesFromPicFolder = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/images/pic/"));
            string[] imagesFromDefaultFolder = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/images/default/"));
            List<string> allimagesFromPicFolder = new List<string>();
            foreach (string filePath in imagesFromPicFolder)
            {
                string imagefileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                allimagesFromPicFolder.Add(imagefileName);
            }
            List<string> allimagesFromDefaultFolder = new List<string>();
            foreach (string filePath in imagesFromDefaultFolder)
            {
                string defaultfileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                allimagesFromDefaultFolder.Add(defaultfileName);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < allimagesFromPicFolder.Count; i++)
            {
                strHtm += @"<div style='width: 300px; height: 300px;' id='DivNew" + i + @"'>
            <div class='flip'>
            <div class='front'>
            <img id='image' alt='image' src='images/pic/" + allimagesFromPicFolder[i] + @"'  />

              <div>
                    <span class='fa fa-inr' style='padding:77px;margin-top:-81px; color:blue;text-align:center;padding-left:64px;'>" + objSlider.Listcls_SliderMain[i].SliderName + @"</span></div>

            </div>
            <div class='back'>
            <img id='image' alt='default' src='images/default/" + allimagesFromDefaultFolder[i] + @"'/>

              <div>
                    <span class='fa fa-inr' style='padding:77px;margin-top:-81px; color:blue;text-align:center;padding-left:64px;'>" + objSlider.Listcls_SliderMain[i].SliderName + @"</span></div>
            </div>
            </div></div>";
            }
            Slider3.InnerHtml = strHtm;
        }
    }

[![image][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtfYr.png


<style>
        slick-prev
        {
            left: 15px;
        }
        .slick-next
        {
            right: 15px;
        }

        .slick-prev, .slick-next
        {
            height: 40px;
            width: 40px;
            z-index: 9;
            background: black;
            border-radius: 100%;
        }
        .slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before
        {
            font-family: 'slick';
            font-size: 20px;
            line-height: 1;
            opacity: .75;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        }


        .imgslide
        {
            margin-top: 4px;
            display: inline-block;
            border: solid 1px #E4E4E4;
        }

        .multiple-items
        {
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        .slick-initialized .multiple-items
        {
            display: block;
            height: 359px;
            width: 131px;
        }

        /* .flip
        {
            width: 56%;
            border: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
            margin: 0 auto;
            transform: scale(-1, 1);
            -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
            -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
            -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
            -khtml-transform: scale(-1, 1);
            -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
        }*/
        .flip img
        {
            width: 246px;
            height: auto;
        }
        .flip .back
        {
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            width: 246px;
            height: auto;
        }
        .next
        {
            right: 0px;
        }
        .prev
        {
            left: 0px;
        }
        .slick-initialized .slick-slide
        {
            display: block;
        }
        element.style
        {
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            height: 100%;
            width: 246px;
            position: relative;
            transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
            transform: rotateY(-180deg);
            z-index: 0;
        }
        .slick-slide img
        {
            display: block;
            width: 66%;
            height: auto;
        }
        .slick-slide
        {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }
        .slick-slide slick-active
        {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
        }
        .flip
        {
            width: 342px;
            margin: -66px auto;
            padding: 1px;
            border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
            transform: scale(-1, 1);
            -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
            -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
            -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
            -khtml-transform: scale(-1, 1);
            -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
        }
    </style>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Flip/1.1.2/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.multiple-items').slick({
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,

      arrows: true,
    });
  });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".flip").flip({
                trigger: 'hover'
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".flip").flip({
                trigger: 'hover',
                axis: 'y'
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#image').mouseover(function () {
            $(this).addClass('flip');
        }).mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('flip');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="Slider3" class="multiple-items" runat="server">
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add all relevant code (minimal version) to your question: where is the code flipping your image?

Comment: check it i have added